# Removing double white lines in Latex table

Tags: tables, columns, tabularray

I have compiled the following table.

[image]

I want to remove these white lines and replace them normal single black lines. I can not find where I specifically coded these white lines to appear. My MWE is as shown:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize,
        labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}




\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\fontsize{9}{10}\selectfont
\centering
\caption{A table with strange lines}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
         colspec = {|X[3,c,m]|X[c,m]|X[c,m]|X[c,m]|X[c,m]|X[c,m]|X[c,m]|X|[c,m]|},
         column{1} = {font=\bfseries},
         column{2-Z}={font=\fontsize{7}{9}\selectfont},
         row{1} = {ht = 6ex},
         row{1} = {bg = green7},
         row{1} = {font =\fontsize{9}{6}\selectfont},
         hspan=minimal}
\textbf{Experiment no.}   & {{{\textbf{Na}}}} & {{{\textbf{Mg}}}} & {{{\textbf{Al}}}} & 
{{{\textbf{Si}}}} & {{{\textbf{K}}}} & {{{\textbf{Ca}}}} & {{{\textbf{Fe}}}}     \\
Some text here      &-1.36 & -0.49 & -1.26 & -1.39 & -0.19 & -1.16 & -1.27  \\
Some text here      &0.23  & 1.59  & 4.27  & 3.55  & 4.59  & 1.26  & 4.33  \\
Some text here      &-2.83 & 0.55  & -0.64 & 1.83  & 0.03  & -1.11 & -0.97  
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Any guidance will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you remove all occurrences of | (vertical line) in your colspec line?

Comment: Works. Thank you again. I guess I did code it in then...  :-(

Answer (score 2):

The issue you observe is caused by the combination of `vlines` and `|` inside of the `colsep` part of your code. As demonstrated in the following more minimal example, getting rid of either of them solves the issue:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
         colspec = {|c|c|c|}, % with vlines and |
         row{1} = {bg = green7}}
Experiment no.      & Na   & Mg    \\
Some text here      &-1.36 & -0.49 \\
\end{tblr}
\smallskip

\begin{tblr}{hlines, % without vlines
         colspec = {|c|c|c|},
         row{1} = {bg = green7}}
Experiment no.      & Na   & Mg    \\
Some text here      &-1.36 & -0.49 \\
\end{tblr}
\smallskip

\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
         colspec = {ccc}, % without |
         row{1} = {bg = green7}}
Experiment no.      & Na   & Mg    \\
Some text here      &-1.36 & -0.49 \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

---

Some off-topic suggestions regarding your particular table: You can get rid of all occurences of `{{{`and `}}}` in the first row of your table. They are only needed if you use `S` type column, which you don't use in this table. You can also remove all `\textbf` commands from the first row and simply use `row{1} = {font =\fontsize{9}{6}\bfseries},` instead.

Comment: Note that `\selectfont` is not needed in `font` option; `tabularray` adds it by default.

Comment: @L.J.R.: Thanks for the info. I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Would there be a manual available that details how tabularray with LATEX3 works? I have seen https://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf , but there does appear to be much detail.

Comment: *does not appear to be much detail

Comment: @HK94 I am the author of this package. I will try to add more and more details to the manual in the following releases.